# INSERT INTO SQL Server a single value using odbc library with R

Tags: sql-server, r, odbc

I want to insert a single value on SQL table with R using odbc library

To do it, I create the conection, and when it is done, then, I try to insert the data on it, using this comand:

```
odbc::dbSendQuery(con,"INSERT INTO Datos_Moldeo (Referencia) VALUES ('UNASjkjkjk');")
```

But this return me this result:

```
<OdbcResult>
  SQL  INSERT INTO Datos_Moldeo (Referencia) VALUES ('UNASjkjkjk');
  ROWS Fetched: 0 [complete]
       Changed: 1
Warning message:
In new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : Cancelling previous query
```

What´s happening? What i am doing wrong?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

The `dbSendQuery` function is select queries only. You need to use `dbWriteTable` or `dbSendStatement` to write to it.

Comment: Good answer!! It would be better if you can add some comment/code too.

Answer (score 1):

`dbSendQuery` is driver specific. In some cases it may work but it is not recommended to use for update/insert.

Alternatively you can use `dbExecute` method.

```
dbExecute(con,
  "INSERT INTO Datos_Moldeo (Referencia) VALUES ('UNASjkjkjk');")
```